# No change in graduated symbol size in map, the change occur only in layer panel

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology, legend

[image]I want to make a map of India with the population in some cities, with symbol size ranging from smallest to largest according to the population value. I used graduated symbol. I have 13 categories of population and I customised the symbolize from 0.8mm to 15 mm. I want to make the size of large population symbol a bit larger than this. But when I change the largest symbol size from 15 to 25 or 35 no change occur in the map symbols. Only the size of symbols in layer panel is changing.

Is there any way to enlarge the symbol?

I am using QGIS version 3.18.1.
I am adding the screenshot of how I changed the size of symbol.

the layer styling panel looks like this.
[image]

Comment: How did you scale the symbols? Did you use the date-driven override/assistant? Can you post a screenshot of where you changed the symbol size from 15 to 25?

Comment: I didn't use data-driven override ,I just change through the size option in the layer properties. Actually I changed the upper symbol size from 15 to 25.  I  will add the screenshot of it.

Comment: When you click `apply`, the dots (circles) on the map canvas should change. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes ,there is no change in symbols even if I give the upper limit as 65 instead of 15 .That's where I got stuck.Even decreasing it to 3 from 15 makes no change . It still standing at the moment when I gave the upper limit as 15 and lower limit as 0.800

Comment: Strange. Set the layer rending style back to Single symbol and try using `size / data driven override / assistant`, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/syNaN.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Sw5.png - does this help? If not: can you change the styles at all (color etc.)? If not: check if `Live update` has not been disabled accidentally: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392993/88814

Comment: But I think when I shift to single symbol ,I cannot make the legend range wise You can see from the above screenshot that my ranges are like 57436-67890,78950-98750.For making it as this type  I shifted to graduated symbol. No what would I do?

Comment: I see. Can you try using the layer styling panel and check if everything looks like on my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JvhH.png ? Maybe you can post a screenshot of it to see where the problem could be

Comment: Yes, I do,it looks exactly as yours to me. I added the screenshot in question.

Comment: @Babel, I deleted the layer . Added it once more and changed the properties,now size is changing. I don't know what happened earlier. NOw it's okay. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, good to know. Often it helps to restart everything to get a fresh start.