# Persistent shapes in project not attached to layer

Tags: qgis, layers

I am running QGIS LTR.  I was attempting to digitize some shapes to fix geometry.  Selected the layer, toggled edit, used the add polygon feature to trace, then right clicked to end.  I see where it maybe should have been a control-click.  In any event, I now have a number of polygons that are not attached to any layer, that are always on top.  I cannot get rid of them.  I tried saving to a new project, but they survived.

[image]

These shapes appear with no layer selected.  I cannot select them using the select tool with any of the layers active.  I have tried refresh, and have spent several hours searching for an answer.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I should add that toggling edits after ward does not bring up a dialog box asking me to fill the fields in the database file, and there are no edits to save in current edits.

Comment: Id feature says no feature found at this site.

Comment: And shapes remain on screen even after using "Hide all layers"

Comment: If you close the project, close all instances of QGIS, and then delete the contents of your temp folder, does that fix things?

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392993/88814

Answer (score 2):

I feel like an indiot.  I have spent hours on this and finally figured out that the shapes are in an annotation layer!  The annotation tool bar was turned on, and it has an add polygon feature, which when you click it says nothing about annotation.  I finally noticed the annotation in the layer window of the style box.  Haven't figured how to get rid of it yet, but it is set to 0% opacity, so it is no longer a threat!  Now to go beat my head against the wall for pleasure!

Thanks to all who helped and looked!

Comment: If you have the annotation toolbar visible (you can show the annotations toolbar by going to settings > toolbars > annotations toolbar). Use the "Modify annotations" button to select the annotation shape, then you can press "delete" to remove the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have unchecked `Live update` and `Render` check boxes. In this case, QGIS does not change the map canvas any more. Even with all layers deleted (see empty layer panel), they are still shown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I tried with render and live update checked and unchecked.  No difference.  I think this might be some sort of issue iwth digitizing.  I have created a test file empty, toggled edit, add polygon and added a square.  After a right click to stop digitizing and complete the polygon,, I do not see the diaglog box to fill in the fields, and it does not add a shape to the layer table.  When I toggle edits there are no edits to save.  Plan this am is to start a new project and see if it broken in the new project, or someithing is broken in the existing project.  Will update here.

Comment: When unchecked, move the map canvas a bit/pan around - the geometries still do not disappear?

Comment: The do not disappear.  Something is broken with the digitizing.  I tried a new project to just create some lines.  THey are not in the only shape file, yet they are in the project, when not saved and reopened.  When I shut down Qgis, reopen the same project they are gone - if I didnt save the project on closing.  If I save the project, they are still there.

Comment: I suspect something is broken with my install.  I get an error message on startup that says no module named ee.  (Cant paste screeen captures here!). Also, when I go into settings/options/digitizing and make a change and save it, I get python warnings that somehting has been deleted.  I will try a new reinstall from 3.22 ltr to see if it fixes this mac.

Comment: new reinstall did not help.  I am on a Mac.  I have tried to add  a polygon to a polygon layer.  I see the new polygon on the screen, but the new shape will not add to the table, and when I deselect all layers so none are visible, the new shape remains, and is on top of all the other layers.  I cannot seem to get rid of it.  turning live update and rendering off have no effect.  Close the project without saving, and then reopen the project brings the shape back.  It go away is to close the project without saving and shut down Qgis and restart.

Comment: Zooming in and out does not help? Did you check geometries for errors? Can you share your data?