# QGIS CRS changes don't affect visual map correctly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to change a world map CRS to create a nicer looking map.  No matter what CRS I choose it always looks similar.  I've tried changing the project CRS as well as the layer CRS. This is all with a shapefile downloaded from [here](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/)

I had it working for a bit then I got the qgis exception error 'fallback transform failed'.

I'm using QGIS 3.16.16

This is with both project and layers as World_Robinson ESRI:54030.  Definitely not how it's supposed to look.

[image: both project and layer as World_Robinson ESRI:54030]

Comment: To change the projection of the map canvas, only change project CRS, **not** layer CRS! See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814 If nothing changes, make sure to have activated `Live update`, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392993/88814 If it still doesn't work, you should provide more information. Also try to save the project and restart QGIS.

Comment: Load pre-installed OpenStreetMap basemap from XYZ-Tiles entry in layer panel to check if the loaded layer is located in the right place. Probably not, as you changed layer's CRS.

Comment: Never change layer CRS.  Loading that data into QGIS and setting the project CRS to World Robinson works fine - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7Jh.png).

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.